# Can we mock 2nd object creation using powermock

Tags: java, powermock

We can mock the object creation using powermock using below line:

```
MyClass myObj = getMyObj();

PowerMockito.whenNew(MyClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myObj);
```

Now in my class where I am writing test case, I have logic of this kind:

```
public class TestClass {

   public void testMethod() {
      MyClass obj = new MyClass();
      boolean flag = doSomeOperation();
      if(flag) {
        MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
        //doSomeOtherOp();       
      }
   }
}
```

Here I want to mock the second object creation `obj1`, is it possible with powermock to control which object I want to mock. Here I don't want to mock the 1st object `obj`.

Answer (score 2):

I thought this to be simple:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(MyClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(firstResult)
  .thenReturn(anotherResult);
```

but unfortunately, although chaining is possible in other contexts, it seems that PowerMockito doesn't allow for it.

( Something like

```
when(someMock.toString()).thenReturn("a").thenReturn("b");
System.out.println(someMock.toString() +factory.toString();
```

just nicely prints `ab` ! )

So the only answer I can give right now: you wrote hard to test code. Consider not doing that.

Instead of relying on PowerMock to mock calls to `new()` you should rather step back and change your design. For example by using a **factory** in your production code. So instead of calling `new()` directly, you simply ask the factory for new instances. And that factory can be easily mocked without the need of PowerMock(ito).

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried thenReturn 2 times: `You probably stored a reference to OngoingStubbing returned by when() and called stubbing methods like thenReturn() on this reference more than once.`

Comment: Sorry, for now, I dont have a technical answer. On the other hand, I see that error as another symptom of the same problem: you should **not** be doing this. At all. Because hard-to-test code is fixed by changing it, not by fighting with mocking frameworks.